# Change Time format for fullCalendar version 4

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Problem: the time in fullcalendar month view is displayed as 12h+am/pm. If you change the locale to spanish, it changes to H (without minutes)

I want to show it always, for all locales, as H:mm. In all the previous answers I found to this same question, the solution is use the option timeFormat: "H:mm", but it doesn't seem to work in fullcalendar v.4.2 (current). This is what I tried:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
    axisFormat: "H:mm",
    timeFormat: "H:mm"
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mariavilaro/esxrb8mw/2/

Any tip for acomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution just before hitting the submit button. In fullcalendar v.4 the correct option for the time format is [eventTimeFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat), so this would be the correct code for showing the time as H:mm:

```
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
  omitZeroMinute: false,
  meridiem: false
}
```

I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariavilaro/esxrb8mw/7/).